# REST addon error?

Tags: channel-entries, templates, add-on, addons, rest

I'm trying to use http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/rest. In a few of my pages, I am getting this error when I enable debug mode:

A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: Warning
Message: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
Filename: rest/pi.rest.php
Line Number: 351
```

The relevant part of the code in `pi.rest.php` is this:

```
// Format dates to unix timestamps
elseif (isset($this->EE->TMPL->date_vars[$index]) and ! is_numeric($child))
{
    $child = strtotime($child);
}
```

I've tried outputting the value of `$child` before the `strtotime` call, and I see:

`array(1) { ["profile_name"]=> string(18) "John Doe" }`

The output is the array representation of the JSON string I expect to be returned to me.

Any ideas what be causing my issues?

**UPDATE 1:**

One of the problems exist when the REST tags are called from inside:

```
{exp:low_search:results
   {if embed:query}query="{embed:query}"{/if}
   collection="forum_topics"
   disable="categories|category_fields"
   limit="25"
   paginate="bottom"
   orderby="date"
   sort="desc"
}
```

When I replace that with just `{exp:channel:entries}` (and remove the `query` param, and replace `collection` with `channel`), the problem is gone. So, it has something to do with Low Search???

**Update 2:**

The other place where this add-on is having issues is when it is inside of:

```
{exp:friends:mine
    member_id="CURRENT_USER"
    reciprocal="y"
}
```

**Update 3:**

I did a `var_dump` in the part of the code that encounters the error. `$this->EE->TMPL->date_vars` has the value `array(1) {  [0]=>  string(10) "entry_date"}`. `$index` is `int(0)`. And `$child` has the array that I need.

Comment: Which version of EECMS are you using, please?

Comment: 2.8.1 - hope this helps!

Comment: Yeap, it helps. Please, show us the part of the template where the value of `profile_name` should appears.

Comment: Did you fix this? What ended up being the solution? I am struggling with the same issues. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExpressionEngine has had some updates to do date localization and relative dates. The particular line from the core that is causing your issue is `Line 4166` in `expressionengine/libraries/Template.php`.

There are a number of solutions here for your problem.

Ideally line 349 should check to make sure it is a string as well because `strtotime` will only work as expected with a format string.

```
isset($this->EE->TMPL->date_vars[$index]) && is_string($child) && !is_numeric($child))
```

Additionally it could utilize a different tag parameter as well on line 65.

```
$format = $this->EE->TMPL->fetch_param('response_format', 'xml');
```

Either of these changes should do the trick for this scenario, personally I would do both.

If you have a response that comes back as a numeric string it will still try to process it as a date if you don't change the template tag.

I believe the reason you are seeing it only with the `low_search` tag is because you are triggering date processing with the `orderby="date"`.

Answer (score 1):

EE 2.8 will consider any tag variable that contains "format=", "timezone=", or ":relative" a date variable. Do you have any tags within your exp:rest tag pair that contain any of those phrases? For example, these made up variables would be considered date variables: `{foo format="%Y"}`, `{bar timezone="America/Chicago"}`, and `{oldest:relative}`.

Comment: Yes, `{exp:rest url="/api/profile-images/" format="json" param:current_profile_member_id="{author_id}" parse="inward" random verb="get"}` -- but it only causes problems in some pages, not all. I'm still not sure how they are different from page to page (I'm pretty much copying/pasting the code). Anyway, so it does contain `format` -- why it that a problem?

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: I'd try to `var_dump($this->EE->TMPL->date_vars);` where that error is occurring in pi.rest and see what the hell is in there. It sounds like for some reason it's grabbing exp:rest as a date var because of the format= parameter.

Comment: May as well `var_dump($index)` while you're in there.

Comment: Since rest is a plugin and not a module, can you try adding `parse="inward"` as a parameter to your `{exp:rest}` tag and see if that works?

Comment: `parse="inward"` already being done. Look at my first reply to your answer.

Comment: Rob, I did the var_dumps. Please look at my Edit 3.

Comment: I'm gonna call this a bug in the Rest plugin. It should check that the value is a string before passing it to strtotime.

Comment: Do you have an {entry_date format=} tag in between your {exp:rest} tags? That's the culprit.